# Search a string by a mix of syntactical and regex patterns

Tags: regex, r, nlp, tm, part-of-speech

I would like to use R to search a text for patterns expressed through a mix of POS and actual strings. (I have seen this functionality in a python library here: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-search).

For instance, a search pattern could be: `'NOUNPHRASE be|is|was ADJECTIVE than NOUNPHRASE'`, and should return all strings containing structures like: "a cat is faster than a dog".

I know that packages like `openNLP` and `qdap` offer convenient POS-tagging. Has anyone been using the output of it for this kind of pattern maching ?

Answer (score 2):

As a starter, using `koRpus` and `TreeTagger`:

```
library(koRpus) 
library(tm)
mytxt <- c("This is my house.", "A house is better than no house.", "A cat is faster than a dog.")
pattern <- "Noun, singular or mass.*?Adjective, comparative.*?Noun, singular or mass"

tagged.results <- treetag(file = mytxt, treetagger="C:/TreeTagger/bin/tag-english.bat", lang="en", format="obj", stopwords=stopwords("en")) 
tagged.results <- kRp.filter.wclass(tagged.results, "stopword")
taggedText(tagged.results)$id <- factor(head(cumsum(c(0, taggedText(tagged.results)$desc == "Sentence ending punctuation")) + 1, -1))

setNames(mytxt, grepl(pattern, aggregate(desc~id, taggedText(tagged.results), FUN = paste0)$desc))
#               FALSE                               TRUE                               TRUE 
# "This is my house." "A house is better than no house."      "A cat is faster than a dog."
```

Comment: thanks, that's quite nice. Is there a way to mix POS-tags and actual words ? For instance, if I want only cats as the first noun: "cat*?Adjective, comparative.*?Noun, singular or mass" ?

Comment: Well, I guess that's possible, too. One strategy could be to concatenate words and wordclasses, before applying the regular expression.